# How can you setup encrypted swap with swapspace?

Tags: encryption, swap

Command swapspace can be used to have dynamically sized swap memory, but how do you setup encryption with it?

Comment: Unfamiliar with `swapspace`, doesn't appear to be standard/pre-installed. Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/248158/how-do-i-setup-an-encrypted-swap-file or http://askubuntu.com/questions/276374/is-ecryptfs-setup-swap-persistent not work?

Comment: @Xen2050 I think running `ecryptfs-setup-swap ` is not a solution, because it only encrypts swap files created before running it, as Dustin Kirkland tells in his answer in the second link you gave. The idea of `swapspace` is to create swap files dynamically. In the first link swap file is created beforehand, too.